# global Tag Stopped Working : Wrong way to define global variable?

Tags: php, database, global-variables

I'm trying to pull data from the server without having to repeat `$parentQ`, `$parentResult`, and `$link`. I thought adding global inside each function would fix it, and it did.. but for whatever reason just stopped working.

If I put them back inside the function, it works. I'm confused. Why did it work, and now, isn't working. I didn't change anything that I know of. Here's the code:

```
//URL in Reference
  $URL = 'path/file.php';

//Initialize Query for Table Data
$parentQ = "select * from cdi_content where URL=\"$URL\"";
$parentResult = mysql_query($parentQ); // Run the Query
$link = mysql_fetch_assoc($parentResult); // Query Result

// Write Main Content
function writeContent($URL){
global $parentQ, $parentQuery, $link;
echo $link['Content']; // Pull Data From Server
```

Comment: what you get var_dump($link) before function ?

Comment: `bool(false)`. `$link` is also used in a drop menu.

Comment: can echo your query and run into mysql ?

Comment: Not sure I understand... It only works if I put the `$parentQ`, `$parentResult`, and `$link` inside the function... thinking maybe I misunderstand global? I'm reading around... do I have to make a class?

Comment: I just want a clean, simple way to call data from the database. Typing 3 bulky lines in each function seems like a bad choice.

Answer (score 0):

Define `$parentQ`, `$parentResult` and `$link` as global outside the function as well.